# Hello, I need help to solve this problem: Trying to get property 'combustivel_id' of non-object in

Tags: php

I need help to resolve the error : Trying to get property 'combustivel_id' of non-object in

This is my code, with php's tpl extension:

```
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <label for="combustivel_id" class="control-label">{$lbl_combustivel_id}</label>
            <select id="combustivel_id" name="combustivel_id[]" class="form-control">
                {if isset($combustiveis)}
                    {foreach from=$combustiveis item=combustivel}
                    <option value="0">{$select_it}</option>

                     {$combustiveis = ($combustivel_id)}
                        {if (in_array($combustiveis, [$combustivel_id]) === true)}
                            <option value="{$combustiveis->combustivel_id}" selected>{$combustiveis->nome}</option>
                        {else}
                            <option value="{$combustiveis->combustivel_id}">{$combustiveis->nome}</option>
                        {/if}

                    {/foreach}
                {else}
                    <option value="0">{$no_regiter}</option>
                {/if}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what is the type of $combustiveis?

Comment: Is an array....

Comment: I think the line `{$combustiveis = ($combustivel_id)}` doesn't make sense

Comment: Do you have any better ideas than that? I need to use in_array...

Comment: There are so many mistakes in the code. `$combustiveis->` should be `$combustivel->` then this line not making any sense `{$combustiveis = ($combustivel_id)}` write it properly. This `if (in_array($combustiveis, [$combustivel_id]) === true)` condition not making any sense, correct it.

Comment: `$combustivel_id` is this a selected value variable?

Comment: I agree with @VijayHardaha, there are so many errors.  I don't know the syntax for tpl, so I cant post an answer that would work.  This `<option value="0">{$select_it}</option>` should probably be `<option value="$combustivel">{$select_it}</option>`.  But I dont know what $select_it is.    **Please post your html from the browser**